# How to write a line from one txt file to another?

Tags: python, csv, parsing, writetofile

I have to parse some data, I've successfully made a script that finds the start and end of the test, and will print out the data in between those.

Python, the line here is from the csv library

```
    else:
        print(line)
        # csv_file = open(title+'.txt', "w")
        # writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        # csv.writer(csv_file).writerow(line)
```

the csv writes extremely funky data instead of the line as a row. Printing out the line looks exactly as it does in the txt file.

Comment: Why are you using the `csv` module to write a plain text file? CSV is for Comma (or Character) Separated Values. Skip the `csv` part; `open` the file and call `write` on it.

Comment: The awnser to why am I doing X will always be I have no idea what im doing lol. The line is in csv format, with data separated by commas so i assumed use a csv writier. But i see now the error in that.

Comment: Make sense! But then you should be using a CSV _reader_ as well. It will parse the line into a Python list, with one item for each column. This is what the CSV writer expects. (Depending on CSV dialects, the written line might not be exactly identical, though.) But if you don't need to inspect or manipulate individual columns, you might as well skip the CSV reading and writing altogether and keep everything as simple strings.

Comment: BTW, the reason you got "extremely funky data" is because the `line` string you passed is an iterable, and iterating over it results in individual characters. The CSV writer then writes each character to its own column, possibly quoted. `T,h,a,t," ",g,e,t,s," ",m,e,s,s,y,.`

Comment: Yup spot on, that's exactly the issue i was getting. Simply doing writelines and passing a list worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

*Printing out the line looks exactly as it does in the txt file.*

[`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function does accept optional `file` argument so if you want to write file exactly like it would look at stdout you might do

```
...
with open("file.txt","w") as f:
    print(line, file=f)
```

Comment: Might need `end=''` if `line` still contains a newline character at the end. Otherwise you end up with a blank line every other line.

Comment: I ended up taking each line, appending a list and then one line befor the end tag writing the list to a txt file.